# How to call a Dll that references another Dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have  a `Reference.dll` that wrtite by C++. Im also wrtire C# dll that called `Main.dll`, the `Main.dll` use some function in `Reference.dll`. everything build dll is ok, but when i bring all dll to winform application to test. the fucntion in `Main.dll` cannot call and method in `Reference.dll` and make

> ERROR: the source file is different from when the module was built

and when continue debug it continue.

> ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'Reference.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comment: `Reference.dll` should be placed in the binary folder of your test  winform application.

Comment: Remove all references to the DLLs, clean solution, delete all the BIN and Obj folders, do a full build, then  add the references back again.

Comment: IM also reference back again and place dll in the binary folder but it Error :Could not load file or assembly 'Reference.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comment: The first error message is not relevant to your question. It's just telling you that your source files don't match the assembly being debugged (not great, but not causing your crash either). The error loading the assembly, if you are 100% sure that the `Reference.dll` assembly is in fact present in the same directory with the program, is most likely happening due to some DLL that _it_ in turn references and which is missing. You need to double-check and make sure _all_ of the necessary DLLs are present. You may find additional details for the error in the event log; run Event Viewer and look.

Comment: Im try all but not working. my Reference.dll writing by C++ on visual studio 2013 and it working. but when i give Reference.dll to my friend used in visual studio 2012 and it make ERROR:Could not load file or assembly 'Reference.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. im debugiing and see that in moudue of debug not load my dll